# In a matlab gui pressing spacebar (un)checks a checkbox if it is focused. How can I turn this behaviour off?

Tags: matlab, user-interface, checkbox, hotkeys

I have a matlab gui made with guide that has a checkbox uicontroll. When that checkbox is focused, pressing spacebar (un)checks that checkbox.
I don't want this behaviour - how can I turn this off?

I want to turn it off because I have defined a keypressFcn for the spacebar and I want something else to happen when the user presses the spacebar. atm that 'something else' is working. If spacebar is hit, my keypressFcn runs and does what it should do and additionally the checkbox (un)checks. I only want it to execute my keypressFcn, though..

I don't really know where to start solving this problem.. Just some generall direction instructions would already be helpfull!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the similar issue. My solution was to set up a dummy uicontrol (like a text Style with empty String), and in any uicontrol CallBack, I always call uicontrol(dummy) to have the dummy uicontrol focused, so spacebar press will have no effect. It doesn't sound a good solution, but it works well for me.

```
dummy = uicontrol(gcf, 'Style', 'text'); % use this for focus
ckbox = uicontrol(gcf, 'Style', 'CheckBox', 'String', 'myCheckBox', ...
         'Callback', @(h,e)uicontrol(dummy), 'Position', [100 200 100 32]);
```

If you now click the checkbox, it will change its value, and the callback will move focus to the dummy text, so spacebar won't change its value anymore.

If user may press TAB key, it will cycle eligible uicontrols, and if focus lies on the checkbox, spacebar will change its value again. My solution for this is to do uicontrol(dummy) in the KeypressFcn so dummy will be on focus after TAB press.

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work. Spacebar still changes the state of the checkbox..   Despite of the `uicontrol(dummyTextHandle` commant in the first line of the callback, the checkbox is still in focus (There is still a rectangle of dotted lines around the string of the checkbox in the gui when u press on it). Thus, spacebar still changes the state of the checkbox..

Comment: You could try from command window to create two uicontrol, one checkbox and the other dummy text. Then try uicontrol(myHandle) to switch focus between the  two uicontrol. It works as I just tested. What Matlab version are you using?

Comment: Instead of creating a dummy, have you tried `set(gcf, ''CurrentObject'',gcf)`?

Comment: I tried the 'CurrentObject' aproach. It doesnt work. Sure, the 'matlab focus' is now on the figure. But there is still a rectangle of dotted lines around the string of the checkbox in the gui when u click on it. Hence Spacebar still changes the checkbox.  @XiangruiLi I don't want the user to do anything from the  command line. It should all be gui based. Also: As I explained above the `uicontrol(handle)` command doesn't do it here.

Comment: @AntonRodenhauser I just update the answer so you can test it easily. It does not make sense to ask user to write command line. I was telling you the easy way to verify the behavior. You may be doing something wrong since this works fine for me, both in my application and the test I just did.

Comment: Ok I tested it again and it does indeed work!! I must have been tired and screwed something up yesterday when I tried it! Sorry for that. Now i got it to work!

Answer (score 2):

when I had a similar problem I hacked the KeyPressFcn to bypass the spacebar:

```
function test_KeyPressFcn
    % Create a figure
    figure();

    % Add a check box with a KeyPressFcn callback, which will be called when the user preses a key
    uicontrol('Style' , 'checkBox','KeyPressFcn' , @KeyPressed);


function KeyPressed(src , event)
    if strcmpi(event.Key , 'space')
        % Pressing the spacebar changed the value of the checkbox to
        % new_value
        new_value = get(src , 'Value');
        % Let's revert it to its old value
        set(src , 'Value' , ~new_value)
    end
```

The space bar is still working but you set the checkbox back to its original value!

Comment: Ok that's one way to do it. But I have more than one checkbox. (A gui with multiple checkboxes and a 'apply' button. spacebar triggers the 'apply' button of my gui.) So I would need to find out which checkbox the user selected before he pressed spacebar. I guess that' somehow possible (something like 'find the current uicontroll'). It doesnt matter now anymore, though. @Xiangrui Li s answer works and I made it the accepted answer. I gave yours an upvote though! thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Hi Anton, this solution already handles multiple checkboxes, as long as you set the same `KeyPressFcn` for all of them. In the `KeyPressed` function, hte `src` parameter will point to the calling checkbox, i.e., the one that has the focus.